# ES6 spread syntax : skip empty keys automatically?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is simpler pattern to avoid updating inputs if one of the keys is empty in payload ?
Is there a nice ES6 syntax ?

```
const master = {
    inputs: {a: [], b: [], c: []}
};

const {a, b, c} = payload;

const updateMaster = (payload) => ({
    ...master, inputs: {...master.inputs, ...payload}
});
```

Comment: Object.assign should take care of it

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function like this. It removes all empty values from an object, without directly modifying the object passed to the function.

```js
const removeEmpty = obj => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
    // value is "falsey" or is empty array
    return !obj[key] || (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && !obj[key].length)
      ? acc
      : {...acc, [key]: obj[key]}
  }, {})
}

console.log(removeEmpty({a: 'AAA', b: '', c: 'CCC', d: false, e: null, f: [1,2], g: []}))
```

So your final snippet would look like this:

```js
const updateMaster = (payload) => ({
    ...master, inputs: {...master.inputs, ...removeEmpty(payload)}
});
```

Comment: Using `reduce` like this is reinventing the wheel (`Object.fromEntries`).

Comment: @junvar Do you mean something like `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(...))`?

Comment: @junvar `reduce()` iterates through the array just once, as opposed to `filter` *and* `fromEntries`. For the same reason I always prefer `.reduce()` to something like `filter().map()` as well.

Comment: @TylerRoper One advantage to using from/entries is that the object is only copied twice. In my answer, the object is copied on each call to the callback. Though you could just mutate the accumulator to optimize.

Comment: @Cully True, but that isn't an inherent issue with `reduce`. That could be remedied by modifying the accumulator (as you've noted).

Comment: @TylerRoper Then you may as well just use traditional for loops instead of `map().filter().unique()` chaining. While your at it, you may as well stop using JS if you're so overly concerned over performance.

Comment: @Cully, yes that's what I mean for this example, but also in general, most uses of `.reduce(Object.entries(...` to construct an object, can be simplified by using `Object.fromEntries(...`

Answer (score 2):

To filter the fields of an object, use `Object.entries` to retrieve the fields, `Array.prototype.filter` to filter then, and `Object.formEntries` to reconstruct an object from the filtered entries.

```js
let payload = {
  a: [],
  b: [1, 2]
};

let nonEmptyPayload = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(payload).filter(([_, v]) => v.length))

console.log(nonEmptyPayload);
```

Applying this to your example,

```js
let master = {
  inputs: {
    a: [],
    b: [13, 14],
    c: [10, 12]
  }
};

let trimObj = obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => v.length));

let updateMaster = payload => ({
  ...master,
  inputs: { ...master.inputs,
    ...trimObj(payload)
  }
});

updateMaster({
  b: [15, 16], // Will override master.c
  c: []        // Will not override master.c
});

console.log(master);
```